# How to pass HttpContext.Current to function?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my action of controller i want to use function for to set cookies if they are not installed, and to add in cache some data.

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Search")]
    public ActionResult SearchGet(SellsLiveSearch Per, int page)
    { if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies["G"] != null)
         {...}
       else
         {SearchFunc(Per);}
    }

    public static List<SellsLive> SearchFunc(SellsLiveSearch Per)
    {...
     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
     HttpContext.Cache.Add
           (
             Key,
             Data,
             null,
             DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
             TimeSpan.Zero,
             System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal,
             null
           );
    }
```

But i can't do this, because VS gives error:

HttpContextBase Controller.HttpContext

Error:

For the nonstatic field, method or property "System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HttpContext.get" requires an object reference.

What am i doing wrong and what i need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either pass the context into the function or use `HttpContext.Current` to retrieve the current context.

### Pass it in

```
public static List<SellsLive> SearchFunc(SellsLiveSearch Per, HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
SearchFunc(Per, this.HttpContext);
```

### Get Current context

```
public static List<SellsLive> SearchFunc(SellsLiveSearch Per)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    context.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
    //etc
}
```

Of course, this way will only work if the function is running on the correct thread.

Comment: Second method works so:

HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
     
First will try later

Answer (score 0):

I have got following code to set cookies, you may want to try it:

```
    public void SetCookie(string key, string value, TimeSpan expires, bool isHttpOnly)
    {
        var encodedCookie = new HttpCookie(key, value);

        encodedCookie.HttpOnly = isHttpOnly;

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key] != null)
        {
            var cookieOld = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];
            cookieOld.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(expires);
            cookieOld.Value = encodedCookie.Value;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookieOld);
        }
        else
        {
            encodedCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(expires);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(encodedCookie);
        }
    }
```